# Ansible Tower - Using Azure Key Vault Secrets Within Playbooks

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-keyvault, ansible-tower

I am currently trying to utilize the Credential of type `Microsoft Azure Key Vault` within a playbook. From some googling I have found some resources on specifying `Credential Types` and specifying a custom injector, but would prefer to achieve this with the built in credential if possible.

Currently, I have my key vault credentials properly configured and tested from the UI, and is able to find secrets using the service principal details I have supplied.
[image]

I wish to use this credential to dynamically access and lookup secrets within my playbooks with some sort of command like `{{ my_kv_store }}:secret_name`.
Is achieving this sort of functionality possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to deviate away from trying to use `Azure Key Vault` and went with the Credential Type route instead with the Azure cli within the playbook.

Steps I followed:

New Credential Type: **Azure Service Principal**

```
# Input Configuration
fields:
  - id: vault_url
    type: string
    label: Vault URL (DNS Name)
  - id: client_id
    type: string
    label: Client ID
  - id: client_secret
    type: string
    label: Client Secret
    secret: true
  - id: tenant_id
    type: string
    label: Tenant ID
required:
  - vault_url
  - client_id
  - client_secret
  - tenant_id

# Injector Configuration
env:
  AZ_CLIENT_ID: '{{ client_id }}'
  AZ_CLIENT_SECRET: '{{ client_secret }}'
  AZ_TENANT_ID: '{{ tenant_id }}'
  AZ_VAULT_URL: '{{ vault_url }}'
```

#### Example Credential Configuration

New Credential: **Azure SP Creds**

1. Select Credential Type
2. Select the previously defined Credential Type (Azure Service Principal)
   [image]
3. Provide the necessary input fields

#### Using Credential with your Job

1. Within Job Template

   1. Select **Azure SP Creds**
2. Within your playbook.yml

```
---
- name: grab test-secret from azure kv
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  vars:
    kv_secret_name: "test-secret"
  tasks:
    - name: set facts
      set_fact:
        az_vault_name: "kv-237-gr-vnet-devops"
        az_tenant_id:   '{{ lookup("env", "AZ_TENANT_ID") }}'
        az_client_id:   '{{ lookup("env", "AZ_CLIENT_ID") }}'
        az_client_secret:  '{{ lookup("env", "AZ_CLIENT_SECRET") }}'
        az_vault_url:      '{{ lookup("env", "AZ_VAULT_URL") }}'
    - name: connect AZ CLI to Azure
      shell: |
        az login --service-principal -u "{{ az_client_id }}" -p "{{ az_client_secret }}" --tenant "{{ az_tenant_id }}"
      args:
        executable: /usr/bin/bash
    - name: Retrieve secret and register as var
      shell: az keyvault secret show --name "{{ kv_secret_name }}" --vault-name "{{ az_vault_name }}" --query value -o tsv
      args:
        executable: /usr/bin/bash
      register: azure_secret
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ azure_secret.stdout }}"
    
    # - name: Use creds to get KV secret
    #   azure_rm_keyvaultsecret_info
    #   debug: msg="the value of this secret is {{lookup('azure_kv',secretname,vault_url=url, client_id=client_id, secret=secret, tenant_id=tenant)}}"

- hosts: all
  vars:
    kv_secret: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['azure_secret']['stdout'] }}"
  tasks:
    - name: "Show the secret retrieved from localhost"
      shell: echo "{{ kv_secret }}"
```